# C++ это объявление не содержит класс хранения или спецификатор типа

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
struct st1 {
    string name[2];
    bool active[2];
};
struct st2;
void init() {
    struct st2 {
        st1 tier1;
        st1 tier2;
        tier1";
    }
};
```

Я создал структуру `st1` и попытался дважды использовать её в структуре `st2`. Насколько мне известно, именно так и нужно их добавлять, но Visual studio 2019 показывает ошибку `это объявление не содержит класс хранения или спецификатор типа` на строчку `tier1;` (если написать, к примеру, `tier1.name[0]="Имя";` или заменить все массивы на несколько переменных, то ничего абсолютно не поменяется).
Так же я пытался инициализировать структуру `st2` вне функции, но результат оставался всё таким же.

Comment: Тут даже не соблюдается баланс открывающих-закрывающих скобок. Не удивительно, что это не компилируется.

Comment: Ну извините, я писал, а не копировал этот кусок. Мой код намного больше в проблемном куске, а этот пример полностью отражает проблему, которую я встречаю, недосмотрел, что не дописал скобку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в структуре `st2` присутствует поле `st2` скорее всего из-за этого возникают ошибки. Если я правильно вас понял, то функция `init()` была добавлена от безысходности, потому я ее убрал. В итоге, при написании структуры так:

```
#include <string>

struct st1 {
    std::string name[2];
    bool active[2];
};
struct st2 {
    st1 tier1;
    st1 tier2;
};

int main()
{
    st2 c;
    c.tier1.name[0] = "5";
}
```

ошибок не возникает и спокойно создается экземпляр структуры, который мы можем редактировать, я для примера поменял `name[0]` у `tier1`, вот что получилось после выполнения кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выходит, задать значения для структуры внутри этой структуры не получится так же как обычные переменные? Жалко, потому что именно на это я и надеялся - st1 у меня должна использоваться в нескольких других структурах (например st2, st3, st4 и т.д.) и каждый раз со своими данными в st1. Предполагаю, что в таком случае будет лучше сделать функцию заполнения всех структур и структуру, содержащую их все, чтобы с помощью неё и возвращать всё в нужное мне место

Comment: @YanTheKiller, скорее всего я просто не так вас понял. В структурах можно создавать методы, в том числе и конструкторы. Пример можете прочитать по [ссылке](https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2020/07/21/c-structures-using-methods-in-structures-constructors-in-structures-ru/).     
Просто из вашего вопроса не очень понятно, что именно вас интересует